# Unknown property 'allowedOriginPattern' for type 'org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration'

Tags: java, spring, api-gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway application which supported 'http://example.com' as a origin. So to handle that below was my code:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:          
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "http://localhost:8080"
```

Now the requirement is to handled anything that ends with **host:8080**. I tried to use ***host:8080**, but that is not working.

I tried to find the solution and it seems like we have [addAllowedOriginPattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html#addAllowedOriginPattern(java.lang.String)), but I am not sure how to handle that using my YAML file.

How do I handle a wild card pattern in the YAML file?

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me. I had to remove properties from yaml and add it to class file:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

@Configuration
public class CorsWebFilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {

        final CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();

        // TODO: Read the below values from properties file.
        corsConfig.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList("*localhost:8080", "*abc.com", "*example.com"));
        corsConfig.setMaxAge(3600L);
        corsConfig.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("POST"));
        corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("*");

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);

        return new CorsWebFilter(source);
    }

}
```